# LDAPS with snap install of nextcloud on 18.04

Tags: security, ldap, nextcloud

Installed nextcloud on 18.04 with

```
sudo snap install nextcloud
```

Is there any way to get nextcloud to use a private cert to use LDAPS instead of just LDAP ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working via a workaround, by using stunnel:

```
[ldap]
accept = 389
connect = <ldap server>:636
client = yes
CAfile = /etc/stunnel/ldap.pem
```